# How to reverse shell tool?

Tags: java, android, shell, sockets

I am trying to implement reverse shell tool in Java using sockets.I want to execute shell commands at Android device.I am able to execute commands using **netcat** but when I try my tool to execute commands Android device is not able to execute shell commands such as **ls -l**,**cd**,**mkdir**...

I want to share screenshoots to clarify my problem...

Expected output shown below:

[image]

My tool's output shown below:

[image]

As you see Android device returns error unexpectedly at my tool.

Comment: Seems dangerous to expose the shell on your device... Anyways, what part of your question is Java, exactly?

Comment: I am using PrintWriter to send command from my tool and getting response over BufferedReader. Firstly, I tried using BufferedWriter to send command and I did not get any response. I think nothing related with Java and Android

Comment: How are you executing the commands that you are typing? Because the error message says it doesn't like the hyphen after the `ls`

Comment: Confusing part is that you said. I am running **sh** after connecting over netcat in Android device. Commands should be executed when I type in my opinion. Somehow they are not executed. I have no idea how **netcat** executes command when I type at first screenshoot.

Comment: Netcat simply pipes standard output to wherever you tell it to, so the problem is the `sh` command is likely spitting the arguments instead of reading the entire string. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you need to do to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Android Can't run Linux terminal commands unless busybox is installed, It will give android access  to desired command